# Visual Studio + Qt Addin, PC freeze when building

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2012, freeze

this is a more unusual question so give me a hint when stack overflow isn't the right place for it. ;)

I have a problem with Visualstion 2012 where it freezes every so often when I compile my project. 
I am currently working on a Qt project so the Qt add-in is installed. I am sure you can't remote-fix my problem but I would like to ask what could cause such freezes.

Here are some important infos:

- the PC doens't freeze every time I compile (seems to be a bit random)
- the freeze takes from 5 to 15 minutes. In most cases, it ends with the screen switching to black and then back to "normal"
- I often try to open the task manager which returns an exit code after the freeze which says that the task manager couldn't start
- the PC comes back to life after 5-15 minutes but many applications (incl VS) aren't responding for additional ~5 minutes.
- the hardware components are fine for what I can tell. (I tested HDD and RAM, temps are fine)

I hope you can give me a hint where the cause of the freezes could be hiding. ;)

Comment: Check your PC for viruses. If you can't start your task manager - it's a first symptom of a virus.

Comment: Should avira do the job? 
It's possible but it would be strange...

Comment: What application caused this? It might be relevant to know for Qt users.

Answer (score 0):

**You could start by analyzing what is unique about your system**.

Perhaps you are using an unusual **source control system**, **anti-virus**, **network connections**, **mapped drives** or some weird form of integration that nobody else uses. My guess is that this may be your source control integration or some server connection that is triggering an **unusual locking condition**.

Comment: Hi, 

I could narrow it down to another program which, why ever, locked the PC down every so often when working with VS. I habe no clue why these applications don't like each other but not using the application seems to be a good work around. ;)

Comment: What application is that? It might be relevant to know for Qt users.

Comment: Corel Draw, 

I don't think it has to do with QT / VS but with corel. Maybe I just got lucky with corel not freezing on its own right now.. ;)